# ORA-00911: invalid character 00911. 00000 - "invalid character"

Tags: sql, oracle

```
WITH TRACKSYS_CAMBRIDGE1 AS(

select DISTINCT 
'tracksys' as SOURCE,
  PROJECT_ID_DNV,
  YR,
  TRACKING_TYPE,
  LEGACY_PA_DNV,
  ACCOUNT_ID_DNV,
  CA_ID,
  LNS_PREMISE_ID,
  SOURCE_DOMAIN,
  CUSTOMER_CONTACT_NAME_DNV,
  
  SITE_ADDRESS1_DNV,
  SITE_ADDRESS2_DNV,
  SITE_CITY_DNV,
  CITY_STANDARD_DNV,
  SITE_STATE_DNV,
  SITE_ZIP_DNV,
  ORIGINAL_DATASET,
  PROGRAM_SECTOR_FLAG_DNV,
  PROGRAM_VERBOSE_DNV,
  PROGRAM,
  PROGRAM_STANDARDIZED
  
  ,CASE 
WHEN program_standardized in ('NEW_CONSTRUCTION','RETROFIT','UPSTREAM') THEN 'LARGE_CI'
WHEN program_standardized ='SMALL_BUSINESS' then 'SMALL_BUSINESS'
ELSE 'RESIDENTIAL' END as program_standardized_1,
  
  CORE_INITIATIVE_VERBOSE,
  CORE_INITIATIVE_DNV,
  END_USE_VERBOSE_DNV,
  BCR_ID_DNV,
  BCR_DESCRIPTION_DNV,
  END_USE_IMPACTED_DNV,
  QUANTITY_DNV,
  MEASURE_LIFE_DNV,
  INSTALLATION_DATE_DNV,
  COMPLETE_DATE,
  VENDOR_INVOICE_DATE_DNV,
  VENDOR_NAME_DNV,
  
GROSS_ANNUAL_KWH_DNV,
 
GROSS_ANNUAL_THERMS_DNV,
  UP_PREMISE_ID,
  LNU_PREMISE_ID,
  PREMISE_ID
FROM EE_STAGE.DNVGL_PROJMEAS_COMBINED_V1 


--where  BCR_DESCRIPTION_DNV  <> ('CHP','CHP (MULTIFAMILY)','CHP - CUSTOM')
--and END_USE_IMPACTED_DNV <>'CHP'

where SITE_CITY_DNV in ('CAMABRIDGE',
'CAMBRDIGE',
'CAMBRIDE',
'CAMBRIDGE',
'CAMBRIDGE MA',
'CAMBRIDGEPORT',
'CAMBRIGE',
'CAMDRIDGE',
'CAMRIDGE',
'CANBRIDGE')

and  (BCR_DESCRIPTION_DNV  !='CHP' and BCR_DESCRIPTION_DNV  !='CHP (MULTIFAMILY)' and BCR_DESCRIPTION_DNV  !='CHP - CUSTOM' and END_USE_IMPACTED_DNV !='CHP')


--and   SITE_STATE_DNV ='MA'

  )
  select 
  YR
  , program_standardized_1,
sum (to_number(GROSS_ANNUAL_KWH_DNV)) AS GROSS_ANNUAL_KWH_DNV ,
 sum (to_number(GROSS_ANNUAL_THERMS_DNV))AS GROSS_ANNUAL_THERMS_DNV
 
 FROM
 TRACKSYS_CAMBRIDGE1
 WHERE YR IN ('2013','2014','2015','2016','2017','2018','2019','2020')
 
 GROUP BY
  YR,
   program_standardized_1
 
 ORDER BY YR ASC
```

trying to run this and keep getting this error message

> ORA-00911: invalid character 00911. 00000 -  "invalid character"
> *Cause:    identifiers may not start with any ASCII character other than
> letters and numbers.  $#_ are also allowed after the first
> character.  Identifiers enclosed by doublequotes may contain
> any character other than a doublequote.  Alternative quotes
> (q'#...#') cannot use spaces, tabs, or carriage returns as
> delimiters.  For all other contexts, consult the SQL Language
> Reference Manual.
> *Action:
> Error at Line: 68 Column: 4

It ran perfectly fine without `(BCR_DESCRIPTION_DNV !='CHP' and BCR_DESCRIPTION_DNV !='CHP (MULTIFAMILY)' and BCR_DESCRIPTION_DNV !='CHP - CUSTOM' and END_USE_IMPACTED_DNV !='CHP')` so i dont think the other fields matter

I was expecting it to run but it wont because of line 68... can anyone help?

Comment: Weird error message. There is a comma missing after `PROGRAM_STANDARDIZED`.

Comment: no, it is right before the case statement

Comment: Ah, sorry, you are right.

Comment: Have you checked which part of the code is causing problems? Delete lines of code until it works. Then you know what line is failing and you can dramatically shorten your question.  Also, sort out the formatting, if it's a mess (and it is) the mess hides the issues. Finally, why does your CTE return dozens of columns, when the outer query only uses 5?

Comment: It ran perfectly fine without  (BCR_DESCRIPTION_DNV !='CHP' and BCR_DESCRIPTION_DNV !='CHP (MULTIFAMILY)' and BCR_DESCRIPTION_DNV !='CHP - CUSTOM' and END_USE_IMPACTED_DNV !='CHP')     so i dont think the other fields matter

Comment: No error; https://dbfiddle.uk/ShX1k5g5

Comment: Fix your formatting. Make sure you have spaces everywhere and not control codes. Stop running messy code, tidy code is infinitely more reliable.